# extract terms from a capture group

Tags: regex, logging, pcre, quotes, extract

I am facing a difficulty which I am not able to solve, so I am asking here.

I am parsing logs from a SIEM, where I would like to extract some terms.

Logs format is strict but content varies from one line to the other.
Where some logs will contain a sentence delimited by double quotes eg. "... ... ...", some other at the same place (thus captured in the same capturing group) will only contain - (ascii 45)

I wrote the following regex (pcre) :

```
\s(?P<cap1>\".+\"|\-)\s
```

But I want to capture the '-' symbol as well as the other characters between the double quotes in the sentences.

Is there anyway of doing this ? Something like

```
\s(\"?P<cap1>(.+)\"|?P<cap1>\-)\s
```

(which I know isn't working)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't consume the text twice, or use two separate regexps. Once the `"a-b"` got matched with `\".+\"`, there is no way to get back and re-match `-` in between `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not what I meant, two different lines are processed one after the other: 

Line 1 upuu  unuu uutu yuyy "uu ii oo pp"  iii ooo ppp

Line 2 usuu  uunu utuu yyoy -  iii ooo ppp

And I try to detect both uu ii oo pp and - with the same regex

Comment: Did you mean `\s(?P<cap1>\"[^\"]*\"|-)\s`?

Comment: I uploaded an example here : https://regex101.com/r/sWbLao/1

Comment: the problem with your last regex is that I don't get - in my capture group

Comment: Ok, try `(?P<cap1>\"[^\"]*\"|-+)`

Comment: i tried this already and i get 
Group `cap1` 20-33 `"uu ii oo pp"`
where I would like to get something like 
Group `cap1` 20-33 `uu ii oo pp`  (without the double quotes)

Comment: Do you mean you need [`(?|\"([^\"]*)\"|(-+))`](https://regex101.com/r/sWbLao/2)? Or do you need the named group but still something like above?

Comment: your last regex is working great! would it be possible to catch the result of this in a capture group as I want to use this value after ?

Comment: In a named group you mean?

Comment: yes named group sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a [*branch reset group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html), `(?|...|...)`, to match various patterns but capture always into the same group:

```
(?|\"(?<cap>[^\"]*)\"|(?<cap>-+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ENKDnz/1)

**Details**

- `(?|` - branch reset group start

  - `\"` - a `"`
  - `(?<cap>[^\"]*)` - Group "cap": any 0+ chars other than `"`
  - `\"` - a `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<cap>-+)` - Group "cap": 1+ `-` chars
- `)` - end of the branch reset group.